# AngularJS templateUrl via POST METHOD

Tags: angularjs

i have a directive that returns a template from a url

```
app.directive('mytemplate', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl '/my/template/
    }
});


Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/test/my/template/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
```

however the request method used is GET by default. How could change it to POST instead?

@Developer

i think your solution cannot work, i cant return the html because it is async.

```
app.directive('mytemplate', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl : function(elem, attr){
             $.post('/test/my/template', null, function(response) {
                  //how could i return the response?
             });
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I found another solution which does not need to override the `$templateRequest` service:

```
app.directive('myTemplate', function($http, $compile){
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $http.post('/my/template/').success(function(res){
                 element.html(res.data);
                 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It is because I'm using a framework (Phalcon), and i have a condition there, where if the method is POST, it will return only the view of the current action, where as GET, it will return the view + the main view, which i wont like to include.

Comment: My bad, I read your question wrong.

Comment: I really need this, I made it like so that, i cant access the view via the GET method in the url. So if i  visit `http://localhost/test/my/template`, I can access the view alone, which I'm preventing. I only want the view to be accessed by POST.

Comment: May be a bad solution,  you can have a container as `template: '<div id="container"></div>' and in the directive controller, you can do a post, get the HTML and inject it to the container.

Comment: Why is it a bad solution? I can't make a container, because the directive will be accessed in different pages. I don't want to include the template in every page.

Comment: Oops, what I mean to say is that, Im not sure whether the workaround I mentioned in that comment is a good solution. @noppa has suggested a good method here (but that would affect all the template requests, not only for this directive). The updated solution you have mentioned is exactly what I said in my previous comment; only change is that my suggested solution had an extra container :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override angular's [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) service, which is responsible for fetching the templates.

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$templateRequest', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$q', '$delegate', 
  function($http, $templateCache, $q, $delegate) {
    // Return a function that will be
    // called when a template needs to be fetched
    return function(templateUrl) {
      // Check if the template is already in cache
      var tpl = $templateCache.get(templateUrl);
      if (tpl === undefined) {
        if ( false ) {
          // If you only sometimes want to use POST and sometimes you want
          // to use GET instead, you can check here if the request should
          // be normal GET request or not. If it should, just use $delegate
          // service and it will call the original fetcher function.

          return $delegate(templateUrl);
        }

        // Make your POST request here
        return $http.post(templateUrl).then(function(res){ 
          var result = res.data;
          // Cache the result
          $templateCache.put(templateUrl, result);
          return result;
        });
      } else {
        return $q.resolve(tpl);
      }
    };
  }]);
}]);
```

With this in your app, the original directive code

```
app.directive('mytemplate', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl '/my/template/'
  }
});
```

should send a POST request instead of GET.